# Python Django - Count objects based on owner that is the user

Tags: python, django

I have users who listed their textbook.
I need to count objects in Textbook model and display total count in the side menu.

Here is my Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class Textbooks(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    edition = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rrp = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    textbook_image = models.FileField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('textbooks:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I used Custom template tag

```
class CustomTag(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context['my_custom_tag_context'] = Textbooks.objects.filter(owner=self.user.request).count()

        return ''
```

```
@register.tag(name='get_custom_tag')
def get_custom_tag(parser, token):
    return CustomTag()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Hvd.png)

AttributeError at /
'CustomTag' object has no attribute 'user'. It seems that i cant use filter in template tag.
is there any other way i can filter them and show the count by owner who is logged in?

Here is what i intend to have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pYCx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change below line in...

```
user = context['request'].user
context['my_custom_tag_context'] = Textbooks.objects.filter(owner=user).count()
```

instead of

```
context['my_custom_tag_context'] = Textbooks.objects.filter(owner=self.user.request).count()
```

You can get `user` from `request`.

Comment: I am getting error 
'CustomTag' object has no attribute 'request'.

Comment: What about `context["request"].user` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/Pv5TRhsT
not sure which part but see this link

Comment: @JordanKowal 
class CustomTag(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context["request"].user['my_custom_tag_context'] = Textbooks.objects.filter().count()

        return ''


@register.tag(name='get_custom_tag')
def get_custom_tag(parser, token):
    return CustomTag()

Something like this. gives below error. 

'User' object does not support item assignment

I am sorry i am preety new at django/python

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say : `user = context["request].user` to get the currently logged user. Then you can do `context['my_custom_tag_context'] = Textbooks.objects.filter(owner=user).count()`

Comment: @JordanKowal

Omg! it worked. I can't believe it. I have been stuck in this problem for 4 days.
Thank you. How do i mark it as resolved and give you the upvote.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Glad to have helped. When using django classes like Views, Nodes, etc, you'll get maybe default params (self, context, request, etc.). Always remember to print them to check what they hold. If you `print(context)`, you'd see it holds a few keys like `request`. Always helpful to know what your variables hold.

Comment: Exactly @JordanKowal .

Comment: Thanks guys. 
@JordanKowal thanks for the suggestion.!  i will make sure i do that. 
unfortunetly i can up vote your comment. Unless you post it as answer. I just joined with no reputation.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry about it :)